# How to generate URL for other pages using JavaScript in Symfony2?

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony

Within my Symfony2 application, in order to link to other pages, I've generated the href value using the [path Twig function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-pages).

I maybe wrong but I think I previously read about a JavaScript equivalent but can't seem to find it now. I am generating some html using JavaScript and want to know if its possible to generate the href values to other pages within the application using purely JavaScript.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for this bundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

Then you can do this kind of stuff in javascript:

```
Routing.generate('my_route', {"my":"param"});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [FosJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle).

Lets assume an action of controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/indx/", options={"expose"=true}, name="indexRoute")
 * @Template()
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    (...)
}
```

`options={"expose"=true}` is what is important here.

Now js equivalent of `path` call is just:

`Routing.generate('indexRoute');`